# Время выполнения в миллисекундах .load jqery (анимация)

Tags: jquery, javascript

Здравствуйте.

Есть такой код:

```
<div class="content">
<ul>
    <li class="class-name0"><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li class="class-name1">2</li>
    <li class="class-name2">3</li>
</ul>
</div>

 <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".class-name0").click(function(){ 
  setTimeout( function() { $(".content").load("/1/1.htm div#content") }, 500);
  return false;
    });
  });

</script>
```

В данном случае идет задержка в 500 мс. А как подвязать сюда что-то типа `.animation()`? Мне нужно, чтобы новый блок подгружался плавно с некой анимацией.

Comment:     .load(url, function () { /* любая анимация */ });

Answer (score 1):

У вас сейчас подгружаемый блок грузится в div.content и навигация исчезает - это нормально?

http://jsfiddle.net/boris_U/vrfs11j1/

Comment: Да, навигация там не нужна